# directshow what is the best component to use

Tags: java, c++, swing, directshow, win32com

hi every one there please i need some info 
i have created app using directshow &c++ for image processing 
so the thing is that i need to create a sophisticated GUI  i have used win32 components which don't  fulfill my needs and my expectations plus difficult to tweak specailly with events 
so i got to find a solution i thought about using jni and merge c++'s functionality with java's the swing components .
the other choice is to use the window form(.net) but if i'm right i need to use directshow.net (i don't know how to use it )

Comment: use matlab or comsol components

Comment: no i just need a beautiful interface with panels & area where to draw something 
 
"use matlab or comsol components " are for other purpose

Comment: DirectShow for ... camera capture? Something like this [How to use JavaCV in an applet](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/wiki/HowToMakeAnApplet)?

Comment: Or [JavaFX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/) maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt is most often called the best C++ framework for building GUIs.

Windows Forms is quite nice. Don't be afraid of using DirectShow.Net, it looks very similar to C++ but easier. You can take a look at [GraphEditPlus](http://www.infognition.com/GraphEditPlus/), it can generate DirectShow graph building code in both C++ and C# (for DirectShow.Net), so you can see how semantically the same code looks in two languages. Also, GraphEditPlus itself is an example of Windows Forms application working with DirectShow.

Answer (score 0):

"but if i'm right i need to use directshow.net". 
No, not really. You can create an activex control in C++ that wraps your current code and use that instead in .Net with Windows.Forms.